# Outlook Exchange Account Sends only 5 messages

Tags: c#, exchange-server, outlook-2010

I am sending messages using the following code in Console App Visual Studio 2012.
For some reason when I send from my exchange server account, I can send only 5 messages at once when I run the application.

However if I send from a free `outlook.com` web account, then I am able to send all 10 messages at once. I am not sure if this is a server configuration issue.

**Code Snippet:**

```
public static void SendMail(string recipientEmail, string subject, string body)
{
    using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
    {
        try
        {
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailFrom"]);
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = body;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipientEmail));
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailHost"];
            smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailEnableSsl"]);
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailUserName"];
            NetworkCred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailPassword"];
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailPort"]);
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        }

        catch (MailException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new MailException("Email sending failed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**In the App Config file:**

```
<add key="MailHost" value="Mail.myMail.com"/>
<add key="MailEnableSsl" value="true"/>
<add key="MailFrom" value="myEmailAddress"/>
<add key="MailUserName" value="MyUserName"/>
<add key="MailPassword" value="MyPassword"/>
<add key="MailPort" value="587"/>

<add key="MailTemplatePath" value="X:\MyFolder\email.html"/>
<add key="MailSubject" value="MyEmail Subject"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to send 10 messages in a loop? Or are you trying to send it to 10 recipients at once? This sounds like a rate limit, which you'll receive when using a corporate Exchange or a free Outlook.com account.

I would test this using an SMTP service that's designed for higher throughput, like Rackspace Mailgun (http://www.mailgun.com/). You can send 10,000 messages for free. I use it for all my contact forms as well as notifications, newsletters, etc. The deliverability is much better too. I'd sign up and just swap out the SMTP credentials.

Comment: I am trying to send to 10 recipient at once but to individual email addresses. The Data is in a table, so I am looping through the UserID's and sending to each user email address. It works when I use a free web account. However, the message is confidential and I have to use an in House exchange account. I am just trying to pin things down before I talk to the IT folks.

Comment: It may just be a matter of waiting a suitable period between messages. Here is how throttling works on Exchange 2013 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232205(v=exchg.150).aspx ). Do you know the version of exchange, and do you you get an exception thrown via the code above? Can you let us know the message?

Comment: There are no Exceptions thrown, I can send a hundred messages but I cannot send them all at the same time. No Exceptions. Is there a way I can make this send in increments?